# A cardinal greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$ of countable cofinality

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to find a cardinal $k\ge \mathfrak c$ such that $\text{cof}(k)=\aleph_0$.
It is know that $\text{cof}(\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$. Obviously under CH $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_\omega$. In general (that is, without assuming CH), is is true that there is a cardinal of countable cofinality bigger than the continuum?
The only thing that comes to my mind is to use the sequence $\aleph_\omega,\aleph_{\aleph_\omega},\dots,$ but I am not sure on how to prove that this sequence eventually surpasses $\mathfrak c$ (if this is true)

Comment: you cannot use cardinal numbers in the subscript of $\aleph$ which you did in the second term of the sequence you mentioned because that would violate the Cantor's theorem. Instead you should write that as $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$.

Comment: @Ranjitkumar Set theorists usually abuse $\aleph_\alpha$ with $\omega_\alpha$ as they are technically the same, so the OP's notation is also fine.

Comment: @Hanul: I wouldn't go as far as saying it's "fine". I'd be upset if I saw that in a research paper. But I would say that it is an acceptable behaviour from non-experts (which unfortunately some experts would also keep using once they become experts).

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar That simply isn't so. It's a convention to use ordinals as subscripts to aleph, but in the case of iterating the aleph function it's silly to write the n-th value as a cardinal but as an ordinal when it's the argument yielding the (n+1)-st value. Besides, nesting alephs as shown makes what's going on clearer.

Comment: @Brian: The issue here is that of arithmetic. $\omega+1\neq\omega$ and $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$. So what is the successor of $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$? Is it $\aleph_{\aleph_0+1}$?

Comment: @Hanul Jeon, they are not technically the same. $\aleph_\alpha+1=\aleph_\alpha$ but $\omega_\alpha+1>\omega_\alpha$ which is one of the many properties which makes these two different.

Comment: @Asaf Well sure that would be ambiguous and basically awful notation. But nobody would write $\aleph_0 + 1$ to mean ordinal addition or cardinal successor, and in practice the expression is probably always found in the context ___ $= \aleph_0$ for the benefit of students.

Comment: @Asaf Well, I am not notationally picky to distinguish $\omega_\alpha$ and $\aleph_\alpha$ thoroughly. (I agree that conflating them carelessly is a bad habit, though.)

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar What I mean was that they denote the same set. You are right that $\omega_\alpha$ and $\aleph_\alpha$ denote different notions.

Comment: Let me clear out why I made the original comment in the first place. We know the formula $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$ and we also know by the Cantor's theorem that $\aleph_{n+1}>\aleph_n$ which only makes sense when $n+1>n$ which is only followed by finite numbers and ordinals because by cardinal arithmetic we know that : If $\alpha>\beta$ then $\alpha+\beta=\alpha$ and clearly $\aleph_n>1$ so $\aleph_n+1=\aleph_n$ which violates the first equation and the Cantor's theorem. So finally by this logic: In order for $\aleph_n$ to make sense, $n$ must be an ordinal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two easy options:

1. We know that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha$ for *some* $\alpha$. Then take its $\omega$th successor, which is $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$, which can also be written as $(2^{\aleph_0})^{+\omega}$.
2. Use $\beth$ numbers, where $\beth_0=\aleph_0$, $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$, and for a limit ordinal $\alpha$, $\beth_\alpha=\sup\{\beth_\gamma\mid\gamma<\alpha\}$. Then $2^{\aleph_0}$ is always $\beth_1$ by definitions, and $\beth_\omega$ is where your answer lies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a small question: do you know whether the sequence I wrote does eventually surpass $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Not necessarily. It reaches the first $\aleph$ fixed point, but that's not necessarily above the continuum.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm going to guess that the ordering of the first $\aleph$ fixed point and the continuum is independent.

Comment: @Brian: Obviously, CH implies that it's below, adding $\theta^+$ many Cohen reals (where $\theta$ is any cardinal) makes the continuum larger than $\theta$, and since Cohen forcing is c.c.c. the $\aleph$ function is not changed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, and doh, no guessing required/very straightforward. Thanks.